# How do I make it to where the range is ONLY 3-20

Tags: python, integer

What they want us to do is create a code where I am able to give them the option of only scoring up to 20 grades. They also want me to add an error message if they mess up and go either above or below the numbers asked. This is what I have so far.

```
n=int(input("Enter an integer between 3-20: "))
a=[]
for i in range(0,n):
    grade=int(input("Enter Grade: "))
    a.append(grade)
avg=sum(a)/n
print("Average Score",round(avg,2))
if(avg >= 90):
    print("Final Grade A")
elif(avg >= 80 and avg < 90):
    print("Final Grade B")
elif(avg >= 70 and avg < 80):
    print("Final Grade C")
elif(avg >= 60 and avg < 70):
    print("Final Grade D")
else:
    print("Sorry, Failed Grade")
```

Answer (score 1):

If your python version is 3.8+, you can replace the first line with

```py
while not 3 <= (n := int(input('Enter an integer between 3-20: '))) <= 20:
    print('Input must be between 3-20, inclusive.')
```

The "assignment expression" `:=` sets `n` as the input. Then `(3 <= ... <= 20)` checks whether `n` is between 3 and 20. Input is requested over and over again until this check returns `True`.

Answer (score 0):

This should work and is pretty simple to understand.

```
while True:
    n = int(input("Enter an integer between 3-20: "))
    if not (3 <= n <= 20):
        print("Number not in range 3-20, try again!")
        continue
    a = []
    for i in range(0, n):
        grade = int(input("Enter Grade: "))
        a.append(grade)
    avg = sum(a)/n
    print("Average Score", round(avg, 2))
    if(avg >= 90):
        print("Final Grade A")
    elif(avg >= 80 and avg < 90):
        print("Final Grade B")
    elif(avg >= 70 and avg < 80):
        print("Final Grade C")
    elif(avg >= 60 and avg < 70):
        print("Final Grade D")
    else:
        print("Sorry, Failed Grade")
    break
```